# Ipred package ,Bagging in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, confidence-interval

here is the code that implements bagging using ipred package in R :

```
library(ipred)

library(mlbench)

data("BostonHousing")

mod <- bagging(medv ~ ., data=BostonHousing, coob=TRUE)
print(mod)
```

Its output is just RMSE , but I need the values after bagging.  How can I have it ?
In addition of values, 95% Confidence interval for each value is needed !?

I appreciate if someone help me.

Thanks

Comment: I am not familliar with this particular package but generally you need to use predict function. Something like predictions <- predict(mod, data=BostonHousing). Check ?bagging and ?predict documentation

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I solved the first section of question with your help, but for the second section(confidence interval for each predicted value) has not been solved yet !!!